# Use Color In System Settings in Designer in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Sometimes I find the Design in Visual Studio to be rather limited. Im using Visual Studio 2012 for C# and have defined a Color in the Settings for the project. Is it possible to have that color available in the designer for a winform?

Comment: If you know the colour hex value you can do it in code till you find one you like (that's how I use to do it when I used Win-forms) But there may be an easier way.

Comment: Yes but i would prefer to have it completely dynamic. I have a system setting that relates the Database Connection to a color. I did find a solution though. Ill type up an answer in a second.

Comment: It is a built-in feature, it just takes point-and-click.  Select the control in the designer, use ApplicationSettings in the Properties window and bind the property to the setting.